# PrimeNG p-table dynamic caption

Tags: angular, html-table, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I'm new in Angular7 and PrimeNG. I don't figured out how to pass table caption as variable:

```
<p-table [value]="userSrv.items"  [title]="table.title">
        <ng-template pTemplate="caption" let-title>
            {{title}}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
            <tr>
                <td>{{item.fullName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

or how to insert dynamic `ngTemplate='caption'` (or other template) on ngOnInit component method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to define something like `[title]="table.title"` or `let-title`.

You can symply use caption templating this way :

```
<ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    {{title}}
</ng-template>
```

See working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poukrn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)